# How to cancel Spring @Async task?

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, spring-async

I am using the following
ThreadPoolTaskExecutor Configuration:

```
        @Bean(name = "asyncExecutor")
    public Executor asyncExecutor() {

        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(10);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(150);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(150);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("AsyncThread-");
        executor.initialize();

        return executor;
    }
```

and using this in the service method:

```
    @Async("asyncExecutor")
    public void executeJob() {
    /// running job
    }
```

How can I kill/cancel the running task under @Async? Please share some examples, thanks

Comment: What condition would kill/cancel the task under `@Async`?

Answer (score 0):

A good practice to implement `@Async` method is return a `Future` object from it. Because you need a connector between caller class and the task.

```java
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AsyncResult;

public class MyJob{
    @Async("asyncExecutor")
    public Future<String> executeJob() {
        // running job
        return new AsyncResult<>("Result");
    }
}
```

Now, you could do this in the caller class:

```java
Future<String> jobTask = myJob.executeJob();
jobTask.cancel(true);
```

**Note:** `.cancel(true)` **not guaranteed immediate** effect. It will just call `.interrupt()`. It issues a flag so whenever in sleeping or waiting state, the thread will be stopped. Refer [Thread.interrupt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29)

If you need to stop the thread immediately. And you have a long loop. You can just add a condition in the loop like below:

```java
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AsyncResult;

public class MyJob{
    private boolean stop;

    @Async("asyncExecutor")
    public Future<String> executeJob() {
        stop = false;
        while(!stop) {
            // running job
        }
        return new AsyncResult<>("Result");
    }

    public void setStop(Boolean stop) {
        this.stop = stop;
    }
}
```

And stop it in the caller like this:

```java
myJob.setStop(true);
```